# NSIS: Hide section name and checkbox in IN/UN Components page

Tags: nsis, modern-ui

I using NSIS to install my project. I need to show or hide section based on flag in Uninstall Component page. I used `SectionSetText ${SecId} ""` and now in uninstall component page I
**don't see section text but the checkbox is visible.**
Is there some way to hide the checkbox along with section text?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot toggle the visibility of a section while you are on the components page. The page pre callback is your last chance to configure...

Comment: So is it possible to hide component module section along with checkbox? I am trying on page callbacks.

Comment: You can hide controls in the show callback of the page.

Comment: thank you, i updated in the pre-callback function and working fine now.